# Mongodb, find just one of the names in database when multiple stored

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a problem when finding from our mongoDB.

Imagine having a mongodb like this: {name: John}, {name: John}, {name: Otto} {name: Louise}, {name: Sarah}, {name: Louise}

our web-server.js is like:

```
app.get('/names/*', function(req, res){
 names.find({}, function(err, names){
res.json(names);
}); });
```

i get John, John, Otto, Louise, Sarah, Louise in result. Is there a way i can get only John, Otto, Louise and Sarah?

Comment: instead of names.find({}, function ()) you can use names.distinct("name", function())

Comment: thank you, this helps me :)

But here is my real code, and not dumbed down like with the names:
articleModel.distinct('rootCategory', {title:0, text:0}, function(err, categories){

now im not getting any result. also tried with " instead of '. and i think {title:0, text:0} is for leaving that out from the result.

Comment: You don't have to write {title:0, text:0} anymore. Distinct query will only return you the list of rootCategory. Try the following code : articleModel.distinct('rootCategory', function(err, categories){

Comment: nice :)
but then i'm not returning my subcategory. Maybe i need to change the set up of my json format for the DB.

Comment: Thank you parvin, got a little smarter thanks to you. I will change some other stuff right now so everything will look a little different

Comment: If you can share your real model and what you really want to achieve maybe we can suggest different solutions.

Comment: I'm solving it by using a filter in angularjs instead, got it working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using a filter in the HTML-page. Like this:

```
{Names | unique}
```

The documents can be viewed here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter